# Cocos 2d background map gesture

Tags: background, cocos2d-iphone, gesture

Cocos2d is prety new for me so i don't know what i should do with this situation:

I want to make a game thats something like risk. Now i made a background image like a world map (just to test). and on this map i want a swipe gesture so i can move accross the map on my ipad ( the map is prety big so i want to swipe it arround).

My problem is i don't know what the objects are called i should use. And how i can implement the gestures the best way (do i need to calculate the movement myself?).

Thanks!
Stefan.

Answer (score 3):

You could maybe connect UIKit's Pan Gesture Recognizer to CCDirector's view and handle pan gesture  in CCLayer class. In that way, you could have handle method which moves background with every pan movement. (Code with cocos2d 1.0.1, similar could be done with 2.0 version)

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)] autorelease];
CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[[director openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Handler method would look like this:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
 // If there is more than one pan gesture recognizer connected with this method, you should remember pan and check if gestureRecognizer is equal to pan 

 switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {

        // Do something that needs to be done when pan gesture started

        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

        // Get pan gesture recognizer translation
        CGPoint translation = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer translationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];

        // Invert Y since position and offset are calculated in gl coordinates
        translation = ccp(translation.x, -translation.y);

        // Here you should move your background, probably in oposite direction of translation vector, something like
        background.position = ccp(background.position.x - translation.x, background.position.y - translation.y);

        // Refresh pan gesture recognizer
        [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:gestureRecognizer.view];

        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {

        // Do some work that should be done after panning is finished

        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for this to add an object:

```
CCSprite *objectName = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"fileName.png"];
    [self addChild:objectName];
```

By default, I believe the object will be in the bottom left corner.